# How to call a function from template class in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

this template function is new to me as I'm learning.
I need to pass the compare from BinarySearch() to Comparer() to show how many elements the comparison performs. How can I call the Comparer() inside the BinarySearch() ? This is to find if a string is in the array.

```
#ifndef INTCOMPARER_H
#define INTCOMPARER_H

#include "Comparer.h"

class IntComparer : public Comparer<int> {
public:
    int Compare(const int& a, const int& b) override {
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
#endif
```

```
#ifndef COMPARER_H
#define COMPARER_H

template <typename T>
class Comparer {
public:
    virtual int Compare(const T& a, const T& b) = 0;
};

#endif
```

```
#ifndef SEARCHER_H
#define SEARCHER_H

#include "Comparer.h"

template <typename T>
class Searcher {
public:
    // I need to call the Comparer() inside this BinarySearch().
    static int BinarySearch(T* array, int arraySize, const T& key,
        Comparer<T>& comparer) 
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = arraySize - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        int test;
      
        while (high >= low) {
            mid = (high + low) / 2;
            if (array[mid] < key) {
                low = mid + 1;               
            }
            else if (array[mid] > key) {
                high = mid - 1;                
            }
            else
            {
                return mid;
            }
            return array.template Comparer<int>(1, 2);
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
#endif
```

Comment: `comparer.Compare(array[mid],key);` ?

Comment: I guess that your Comparer::Compare should be static and you would call Comparer::Compare<T>.

Answer (score 1):

`BinarySearch()` takes in a reference to an object that implements `Comparer<T>`. It can call the `Compare()` method on that object when needed, eg:

```
#ifndef SEARCHER_H
#define SEARCHER_H

#include "Comparer.h"

template <typename T>
class Searcher {
public:
    static int BinarySearch(T* array, int arraySize, const T& key,
        Comparer<T>& comparer) 
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = arraySize - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        int test;
      
        while (high >= low) {
            mid = (high + low) / 2;
            test = comparer.Compare(array[mid], key); // <-- here
            if (test < 0) {
                low = mid + 1;               
            }
            else if (test > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;                
            }
            else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

```
#include "searcher.h"
#include "intcomparer.h"

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int key = ...;
    IntComparer comp;

    cout << "found at " << Searcher<int>::BinarySearch(arr, 5, key, comp);
}
```

Comment: this is a good answer and does answer the OP questions, but may double count the compares.  Maybe just call compare once and use the result 2 times.  That way you would only count each check 1 time